# construction of voltage transducer to regulate voltage

Tags: voltage

How do I regulate 80.1 volts dc to 75 volts dc maximum from 600w solar panel Without affecting the output. The maximum voltage required by the inverter is 75 volts and the connection gives me 80.1volts u really need to reduce this. Bear in mind that it's not dc to dc control

Comment: You need to design it for other light conditions too so that means you need to give more information.

Answer (score 0):

If maximum is 75V, go lower, to 48V or 60V at maximum. Then the answer is easy- use a DC/DC converter. I would use a buck-boost or SPEPIC probably, since in solar panel you don't always get maximum voltage, so you will have to both step up and down. In any case note, that doing it with descent efficiency is not easy, so you may prefer to find off-the-shelf products that to the job.